# Unresolved external symbol GLFW

Tags: c++, opengl, linker, glfw

With the following code:

```
#include <GL/glfw.h>

int main() {
        glfwInit();
        glfwSleep( 1.0 );
        glfwTerminate();
}
```

I'm getting this errors

```
1>------ Build started: Project: tutorialtry6, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _glfwTerminate referenced in function _main
1>main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _glfwSleep referenced in function _main
1>main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _glfwInit referenced in function _main
1>c:\users\indrajit kurmi\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\tutorialtry6\Debug\tutorialtry6.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 3 unresolved externals
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

I have added opengl32.lib in linker additional dependencies. How do I solve this?

If you know some link of tutorial where they show step by step how to use OpenGL with GLFW please post it.

Comment: you are missing dome libs. Where do you have opengl32.lib?

Answer (score 1):

Do you realize that you should **build** the `GLFW` library first, and then **link** (because it is not a header-only library) your application against it? If not, then this is what you should do now. If you need more help, come back with **some results** of your attempts and state clearly what is the problem.

**NOTE**: There is no need for a complete tutorial on how to do these simple things as long as you understand the general process of how 3rd party libraries are installed and incorporated into your project.